# Find number of positions containing similar length

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I have started programming in java after a long time. Currently, I am practicing problems from http://codingbat.com/prob/p198640

Below is the problem description:

Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in both strings.

Examples Include:

- stringMatch("xxcaazz", "xxbaaz") → 3
- stringMatch("abc", "abc") → 2
- stringMatch("abc", "axc") → 0

Below is my solution for the problem which passes all the test cases:

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
  int counter = 0;
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
  int[] nums = new int[a.length()];
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    nums[i] = 0;
  }
  for(int i=0;i<b.length()-1;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<a.length()-1;j++){
      if((a.substring(j,j+2).equals(b.substring(i,i+2))) && ((nums[j]+nums[j+1]<2)) & (!set.contains(b.substring(i,i+2)))){
        nums[j] = 1;
        nums[j+1] = 1;
        set.add(b.substring(j,j+2));
        counter = counter + 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

I feel my solution is really inefficient. I think I am using o(n2) time and o(n) space complexity. Is there a way to have a better solution to this problem? Thank you!

Update:
Based on the comments I was able to reduce to only one loop. I am still uncertain if I need o(n) space with the Set. Can I reduce it to o(1)?

Below is my working code that passes all the test cases:

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
  int counter = 0;
  Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
  String longer = "";
  String shorter = "";
  if(a.length() >= b.length()){
    longer = a;
    shorter = b;
  }
  else{
    longer = b;
    shorter = a;
  }
  int[] nums = new int[longer.length()];
  for(int i=0;i<shorter.length()-1;i++){
    if((shorter.substring(i,i+2).equals(longer.substring(i,i+2))) && ((nums[i]+nums[i+1]<2)) & (!set.contains(shorter.substring(i,i+2)))){
        nums[i] = 1;
        nums[i+1] = 1;
        set.add(shorter.substring(i,i+2));
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: You only need one for-loop since the substrings have to appear in the same place

Comment: **Side note**: You don't need to explicitly set `nums` to 0. All values of an integer array default to 0.

Comment: @randnum-1 Thanks for the observation. I made the change to use only one loop. What do you think about the space complexity? Can I do better?

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have the set at all? It is nowhere mentioned that the substrings must be different.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
  public  int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (a.length()>b.length()?b.length():a.length()) - 1; i++) {
      if ((a.substring(i, i + 2).equals(b.substring(i, i + 2)))) {
        counter++;
      }
    }
    return counter;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with a set of arbitrary strings of different length and found that looping 10000 times takes 258ms, under the same conditions the following code takes 130ms:

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;
    Set<Short> set = new HashSet<Short>();
    byte[] longer, shorter;
    if (a.length() >= b.length()) {
        longer = a.getBytes();
        shorter = b.getBytes();
    } else {
        longer = b.getBytes();
        shorter = a.getBytes();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length - 1; i++) {
        short s = (short) (shorter[i] << 8 | shorter[i + 1]);
        if (!set.contains(s) && 
            shorter[i] == longer[i] && shorter[i + 1] == longer[i + 1])
            if (set.add(s))
                counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Since your statement doesn't speek about duplicates, without checking duplicate strings, the following code takes 72ms:

```
public int stringMatch(String a, String b) {
    int counter = 0;
    byte[] longer, shorter;
    if (a.length() >= b.length()) {
        longer = a.getBytes();
        shorter = b.getBytes();
    } else {
        longer = b.getBytes();
        shorter = a.getBytes();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length - 1; i++)
        if (shorter[i] == longer[i] && shorter[i + 1] == longer[i + 1])
            counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: You need to work with char arrays instead of byte arrays. Note that some characters need more than one byte.

Comment: @Henry that's true, but thats only an example, it's very easy to dead with char[] instead of byte[], for example;

Comment: @Henry that's true, but thats only an example, it's very easy to dead with char[] instead of byte[], for example:
    ... 
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  char[] longer, shorter;
  if (a.length() >= b.length()) {
   longer = a.toCharArray();
   shorter = b.toCharArray();
    ...
   for (int i = 0; i < shorter.length - 1; i++) {
      int s = (shorter[i] << 16 | shorter[i + 1]);
                 if (!set.contains(s) 
                      && shorter[i] == longer[i] && shorter[i + 1] == longer[i + 1]) {
    ...